# Adding an arrow to link with children

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Here's a code of the simpliest multilevel menu:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">I am a 1st level link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I am a 1st level link with children and I want to have an arrow next to me (or different background)</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">I am a 2nd level link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">I am a 2nd level link with children and I want to have an arrow next to me (or different background)</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">I am a 3nd level link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">I am a 3nd level link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">I am a 2nd level link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">I am a 1st level link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">I am a 1st level link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Is there a way of selecting links with children and adding them different styling (background, list-style-type icons etc.)? The menu is dynamic so giving ids or classes won't help in this case.

I'd love to see it in CSS3, if not possible - jQuery or PHP would be ok. I want it to be cross-browser ready. But at the moment don't even know WHERE to start?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work using jquery... you can customize the special class to be a background image with an error or whatever you want....

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul a + ul').each(function(){
            $(this).prev().addClass('special');
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .special {background-color: red;}
</style>
```

Comment: +1 - Although you can shorten it to `$('ul a + ul').prev().addClass('special');`

Answer (score 1):

The `:only-child` pseudoselector selects elements which are the only child of their parent.  You can use this in CSS3 to style elements *without* arrows, overriding those *with* arrows.  You can use e.g. the `:first-of-type` pseudoselector for the main selector in an attempt to prevent browsers which do not support `:only-child` from displaying the arrows on all elements.

For example:

```
nav ul a:first-of-type {
    /* :first-of-type for CSS3-incompat browsers; can be safely removed */

    /* Apply arrow code */
    background: ...;
}

nav ul a:only-child {
    /* Undo arrow code above */
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: The :only-child and :first-of-type selectors will become cross-browser in some 5 years (when IE8 drops).

Comment: @Šime Vidas, The OP mentioned CSS3 and is using HTML5; I really doubt they want perfect IE compatibility.  The point of using `:first-of-type` in my example was to *prevent* older browsers from doing the unexpected.

Comment: @stranger The OP mentioned "cross-browser ready". The combined market share of IE6 to IE8 is currently to big to disregard.

Answer (score 1):

This might get you going:

```
$('li>a')
.filter(function(){
    return $(this).next().is('ul') ? true : false;
}).addClass('haveChild');
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the code provided above and created an example using jsFiddle.

View example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uL3hA/)